# There are two positive integers of the form $p-n^2$ such that one divides the other.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math, divisibility

> Let $p>3$ be a prime number.  Consider the numbers of the form $p - n^2$ where $n = 1 , 2 , 3 , ... , \lfloor\sqrt{p}\rfloor$.  Show that there exist two such numbers, $a$ and $b$, that $a | b$.

I tried show that $p - n_{max}^2 | p - 1$. But I’ve found that $p = 107$ is a counter-example.

Edit : $p - n_1^2$ is a and $p - n_2^2$ is b for some $n_1,n_2$

Please give me hints or answers. Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand why you would like to have $p-n_0^2\mid p-1$? What means "such" numbers $a,b$? Do we assume that $a=p-n^2$ and $b=q-m^2$ ?

Comment: I think the question is: for all primes $p>3$, show there exist $1\leq a<b\leq[\sqrt{p}]$ with $p-b^2|p-a^2$.

Comment: I’ve edit the question to clear the confusion.

Comment: Sorry for that, my mistake.

Comment: Do you know which competition this problem comes from?  I have seen it before, but can't remember where it came from.

Comment: It’s from my tutor. It’s assigned! Actually , none of my friends (including me) solved it.

Comment: I don’t know where it came from. Sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $m:=\lfloor \sqrt{p}\rfloor$.  If $p=m^2+1$, then obviously, we have $a\mid b$ if $a:=p-m^2$ and $b:=p-(m-1)^2$.  We now suppose that $p-m^2>1$.

We shall prove that, if $a:=p-m^2$, then there exists an integer $k$, where $1\le k<m$, such that $a\mid p-k^2$.  First, we note that $p< (m+1)^2-1$; therefore, $p\leq (m+1)^2-2=m^2+2m-1$, so
$$a=p-m^2\leq 2m-1\,.\tag{*}$$
Observe that $a\neq m$; otherwise, $p=m^2+a=m^2+m=m(m+1)$, whence $p=2$, but we assume that $p\geq 3$.

Let $X$ be the set of integers $x$ such that $x\equiv -m\pmod{a}$ and $x<m$.  Clearly, $X$ is nonempty.  Take $k$ to be the largest element of $X$.  Then, $k<m$ is given.

Now, if $k\leq 0$, then $k+a\equiv k\equiv -m\pmod{a}$ and $k+a>k$.  By maximality of $k$, we must have $k+a\geq m$.  Note that
$$a\geq m-k\geq m\,.\tag{#}$$
We know that $a\neq m$.  That is, $a>m$.  Because $k\equiv -m\pmod{a}$ and $k\leq 0$, we must have $k\leq -m$.  Thus, by (#), we get
$$a\geq m-k \geq 2m\,.$$
This contradicts (*).  Hence,
$$0<k<m\,.$$
Now, $$p-k^2\equiv p-(-m)^2= p-m^2=a\equiv0\pmod{a}\,,$$
whence $a\mid b$ if $b:=p-k^2$.

For example, when $p=107$, we see that $m=10$ and $a=7$.  Thus, if $x$ is an integer such that $x\equiv -m\pmod{a}$, then $x\equiv -10\pmod{7}$, or $x\equiv 4\pmod{7}$.  Ergo, $k=4$ works.  We can then take $b:=p-k^2=107-16=91=7\cdot 13$, which is divisible by $a=7$.

**Remark.**  This solution does not really use primality of $p$.  We can take $p$ to be any positive integer such that $p$ is not of the form $q^2$, $q(q+1)$, and $q(q+2)$ for any integer $q$.  For example, if $p=1243=11\cdot 113$, then you can take $m=35$ and $a=18$.  Thus, if $x$ is an integer such that $x\equiv -m\pmod{a}$, then $x\equiv -35\pmod{18}$, or $x\equiv 1\pmod{18}$.  Ergo, $k=19$ works.  We can then take $b:=p-k^2=1243-19^2=882=18\cdot 49$, which is divisible by $a=18$.

Comment: Thank you very much.